# Intent in static context

Tags: android, android-intent

I need intent in static class. But when i write intent, MainActivity is red underlined.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(getItemId() == 0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Spacex.class);

                }
            }
        });
```

> com.company.app.MainActivity.this cannot be referenced from a static context

What should i write?

Comment: You can't reference `this` from a static method. Did you actually study the language first?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(getItemId() == 0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Spacex.class);

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass reference of activity context like :-

```
public static void startNewAct(Context con) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(con, MainActivity2.class);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot this.

Comment: Elegant solution.

Comment: Elegant??? You sir, are hilarious

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Intent.setClassName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) which takes strings.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.example", "./Activity");
```